# Can the SceneGraphCollisionChecker add permanent collision filters to the scene graph?

Tags: drake

The API for the `SceneGraphCollisionChecker` seems to indicate that it can make permanent changes/additions to the collision filter of the scene graph. Is this assumption correct?

I have a case where I manually add a collision body to the plant that collides with another body in a non-adjacent link. This collision is not added to the filter by `MultibodyPlant::Finalize` because the colliding bodies are not in adjacent links. I can use the `SceneGraphCollisionChecker` to identify and filter any "default" collisions. However, subsequent calls to a `MathematicalProgram` that uses the `MinimumDistanceConstraint` fail due to infeasible constraints (`drake::multibody::MinimumDistanceConstraint[0]: -inf <= 3.000000 <= 1.000000`), presumably because the scene graph is not actually filtering the collision pair. If I manually add the filter declaration to the scene graph, the constraint now becomes feasible.

Am I doing something incorrectly here, or does the `SceneGraphCollisionChecker` not actually permanently filter collisions in the scene graph? For reference, I'm working off of version 1.19.0.

```py
resource_file = 'drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/urdf/iiwa14_spheres_dense_collision.urdf'
rdb = RobotDiagramBuilder(time_step=0)
resource = FindResourceOrThrow(resource_file)
model = rdb.parser().AddModelFromFile(resource)
n_pos = rdb.plant().num_positions()

# Add a body to the plant with collision geometry that collides by default
... 

# Finalize the plant
plant.Finalize()

# Build the diagram
diagram = rdb.Build()

# Check for possible collisions and add those collisions to the filter
sgcc = SceneGraphCollisionChecker(model=diagram, robot_model_instances=[model],
                                  configuration_distance_function=l2_dist, edge_step_size=0.01,
                                  env_collision_padding=0.0, self_collision_padding=0.0)

nominal_state = np.zeros((n_pos,))

# Check collisions
collision_free = sgcc.CheckConfigCollisionFree(nominal_state)  # -> reports False

clearance = sgcc.CalcRobotClearance(nominal_state, 0.0)
for idx in np.argwhere(clearance.distances() < 0.0).flatten():
    body_1 = sgcc.plant().get_body(clearance.robot_indices()[idx])
    body_2 = sgcc.plant().get_body(clearance.other_indices()[idx])
    dist = clearance.distances()[idx]
    print(f'Collision between \'{body_1.name()}\' and \'{body_2.name()}\' with distance {dist}')
    sgcc.SetCollisionFilteredBetween(body_1, body_2, True)

# Check collisions
collision_free = sgcc.CheckConfigCollisionFree(nominal_state)  # -> reports True

# Solve IK optimization with min distance constraint -> fails due to an infeasible minimum distance constraint
...

g1 = diagram.plant().CollectRegisteredGeometries([diagram.plant().GetBodyByName('body_a')])
g2 = diagram.plant().CollectRegisteredGeometries([diagram.plant().GetBodyByName('body_b')])
decl = CollisionFilterDeclaration()
decl.ExcludeBetween(g1, g2)
diagram.scene_graph().collision_filter_manager().Apply(decl)

# Solve IK optimization with min distance constraint -> no longer infeasible and succeeds
```

### Update:

Expanding on the code I am using to solve IK. My assumption is that the scene graph object itself is holding the new collision filters

```py
# Solve IK optimization with min distance constraint
plant_context = diagram.plant().GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram.CreateDefaultContext())
ik = InverseKinematics(diagram.plant(), plant_context)

# Add constraints
ik.AddMinimumDistanceConstraint(0.010, 0.1)
...

result = Solve(ik.prog(), initial_guess=...)  # -> fails due to an infeasible minimum distance constraint
```

Comment: Quick question: to help improve the documentation, could you direct us towards where in the documentation it indicates "that it can make permanent changes/additions to the collision filter of the scene graph"? At a minimum, we wouldn't want the documentation to be misleading. Alternatively, we might go the other way and make it an enforced invariant, in which case we'd need to bolster the documentation in the other direction.

Comment: It's mostly the naming of the method [`SetCollisionFilteredBetween`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1planning_1_1_collision_checker.html#a87a9e6f72e628e92db913a5f9aa64d3c) that led me to assume that this change was made permanently to the scene graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... MathematicalProgram that uses the MinimumDistanceConstraint fail ...

I don't see the sample code for this?

I have a guess at the problem, though.

The CollisionChecker filtering API only configures its owned contexts; it does not configure the SceneGraph's model value filtering.

To use `MinimumDistanceConstraint` with a CollisionChecker, you need to be sure to pass it `plant_context` that has been given to you by the CollisionChecker.  You can't make a *new* context and expect to match the checker.

Comment: The current `MinimumDistanceConstraint` on master doesn't work with CollisionChecker yet. I will merge https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19760 soonish to enable this feature.

Comment: I'll update the original posting with the code I was using to configure the optimization with the `MinimumDistanceConstraint`. I am currently generating a new plant context to give to the optimization

What object holds onto the collision filters? Is it the context or the scene graph itself?

Comment: Using the context from the collision checker seems to work. Thanks for the quick reply